# Delta lake whenNotMatchedInsertAll behaviour

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I have the following code, where I want to upsert all rows where `newData.metadata_modified > oldData.metadata_modified`

```
    oldData.alias("oldData") \
        .merge(newData, "oldData.id = newData.id") \
        .whenMatchedUpdateAll("newData.metadata_modified > oldData.metadata_modified") \
        .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
        .execute()
```

If I comment out the `whenNotMatchedInsertAll` and execute this code with the same dataset no delta log is generated, which is the **expected** behavior. However once I add this line, running the code within oldData and newData being the same I got the follow delta log.

```
    "commitInfo": {
        "timestamp": 1707280146580,
        "operation": "MERGE",
        "operationParameters": {
            "predicate": "[\"(id#161 = id#13)\"]",
            "matchedPredicates": "[{\"predicate\":\"(metadata_modified#21 > metadata_modified#169)\",\"actionType\":\"update\"}]",
            "notMatchedPredicates": "[{\"actionType\":\"insert\"}]",
            "notMatchedBySourcePredicates": "[]"
        },
        "readVersion": 17,
        "isolationLevel": "Serializable",
        "isBlindAppend": false,
        "operationMetrics": {
            "numTargetRowsCopied": "442",
            "numTargetRowsDeleted": "0",
            "numTargetFilesAdded": "3",
            "numTargetBytesAdded": "1912181",
            "numTargetBytesRemoved": "1912181",
            "numTargetDeletionVectorsAdded": "0",
            "numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated": "0",
            "executionTimeMs": "4611",
            "numTargetRowsInserted": "0",
            "numTargetRowsMatchedDeleted": "0",
            "numTargetDeletionVectorsUpdated": "0",
            "scanTimeMs": "3274",
            "numTargetRowsUpdated": "0",
            "numOutputRows": "442",
            "numTargetDeletionVectorsRemoved": "0",
            "numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceUpdated": "0",
            "numTargetChangeFilesAdded": "0",
            "numSourceRows": "442",
            "numTargetFilesRemoved": "3",
            "numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceDeleted": "0",
            "rewriteTimeMs": "1046"
        },
        "engineInfo": "Apache-Spark/3.5.0 Delta-Lake/3.1.0",
        "txnId": "5b738e63-5712-4fa9-a6f8-c59f60614038"
    }
```

Why it's copying all data if I didn't do any write/delete or update? is there any way to prevent this?